# query in Sql with JDBC

Tags: sql, mysql, jdbc

In my table, I have taken capacity in this form.
`capacity DECL(3,0) UNSIGNED

Is it correct??I am not sure if the above method is correct to do it in this way? if I have to do it with PreparedStatement, how would it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your SQL query is incorrect.

```
SELECT max(f.capacity)-COALESCE(SUM(r.num_seats),0) AS seats_avail 
  FROM flights f,
       reservations r 
  WHERE f.flight_no="CSC585" 
    AND r.flight_no=f.flight_no
    AND r.departure_date="2010-05-31";
```

Java code will looks like

```
String sql = " SELECT max(f.capacity)-COALESCE(SUM(r.num_seats),0) AS seats_avail 
      FROM flights f,
           reservations r 
      WHERE f.flight_no=?
        AND r.flight_no=f.flight_no
        AND r.departure_date=?";

final PreparedStatement stmt = connectionHolder.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString(1, "CSC585");
stmt.setString(2, "2010-05-31");

ResulSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while ( rs.next() ) {
  String seats = rs.getString("seats_avail");
  System.out.println(seats );
}
```

Comment: thanks....do i need to use "final" keyword here??it is of no use?And In the query, r.flight_no = csc585 given...so I can use stmt.setString(3, "csc585") for it??

Comment: You don't need to use "final" if you wish. And you can use stmt.setString(3, "csc585") if you wish.

Comment: stmt.setString(1, "CSC585"); - can you plese tell me why we use 1 here and 2 in other? what does it represent?IF we use ? in our query, then how would it take the required condition?